# what is the built-in javascript function to return the validator state in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, validation

This is a bit of a tough question to ask.  I am using asp.net validators, but I want to tie them to a simple click event which I bind with jQuery.

I have found that I can use:

```
ValidatorValidate($("#<%= rfvFirst.ClientID %>")[0]);
```

to fire the **rfvFirst** validator, but I do not know how to get the actual false return somewhere to tell me that the form is not valid.

All I need is the function or variable or property that I can call on (client side) to tell me if the form is valid.

I hope that makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using validation groups you can do:

```
if (Page_ClientValidate('Group Name'))
{
 //Valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Page_IsValid would tell you whether the Page is valid. you can also use the isvalid property of the validator to validate the individual validator.